# How to trim a very specific part of a string?

Tags: php, html

I have a string that contains an `<img>` tag somewhere in text entered by users. I want to get rid of all the text but keep the image tag but I have no idea how to do that, is it possible?

```
$str = "<img src= 'imagepath'/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
```

What I want it to do is only keep the  and get rid of all the other text and instead look like this:

```
$str = "<img src='imagepath'/>"
```

Comment: @mplungjan I’m doing this off my iPad so on stackoverflow all the curly quotes are wrong

Comment: @mplungjan I don’t want to force users to put an img tag at the start always so might be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of string manipulation, you can do this with PHP by following method.

```
$str = "<img src= 'imagepath'/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
$start=strpos($str, '<');
$end=strpos($str, '/>');
$img=substr($str, $start, $end-$start+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with to capture `<` to `>`

```php
$regex = '/<.*?\>/m';
$str = "<img src='imagepath'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";

preg_match($regex, $str, $result);

var_dump($result[0]);
```

Output is `'<img src='imagepath'>'`

Answer (score 0):

A javascript method to extract the tag :

> Only possible when there is only one `tag` and no extra `<` `>`
> Can use any string extracter like `substring` `substr` ....

```js
var str = "<img src= 'imagepath'/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"

function trimTagOut() {
  var index1 = str.indexOf("<")
  var index2 = str.indexOf(">")
  var slicedTag = str.slice(index1, index2+1) 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = slicedTag;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="trimTagOut()">Trim tag</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```